# buildfire - Need to Set DNS / CName records to buildfire server - to show HTML 5 app in my domain

Tags: dns, cname, buildfire

I am new to buildfire and the first step for my project is to show our app in the browser with our domain.

What DNS records / CName do I need to set in my domain registrar?

Do I need to add the domain somewhere in Buildfire Admin?

Any other considerations for setting up our buildfire webapp?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to the HTML5 version of your app to reflect a specific domain, or something else?

Comment: yes the App should be available for basic functions(login, read content) at myexampledomain.com

Comment: Its probably best to ask customer service to get you your unique link. However if you are in the control panel. You should be able to see if in your [Share Settings] You may need to redirect your domain to the App URL